# How to solve for eigen value of a matrix numerically

Tags: matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I have a 3x3 matrix; I am interested in finding the eigen values and corresponding eigen vector numerically. I know for smaller system we can take determinant and will solve the determinant equation , which results in eigen values. But I have the matrix size which is pretty big; say 1000x1000. To show the problem, I have chosen 3x3 (which is dummy representation of  the actual problem). Now how to compute the eigen values and eigen vectors in python.

```
import numpy as np
eg_matrix=np.array([[-2-x, -4, 2], [-2, 1-x, 2],[4,2,5-x]])
```

The system which is similar to my problem is; lambda_3 corresponds to eigen value.
[image: dynamics stiffness matrix]

Comment: [numpy.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html#numpy.linalg.eig)?

Comment: But its (K-x^2M) how to solve this system

Comment: `x` in your example is undefined.  That code will give a NameError.

Comment: The matrix represent the  dynamic stiffness matrix. x is the frequencies/ eigen values

Comment: Is your original matrix in the form `M - xI`, like `np.array([[-2, -4, 2], [-2, 1, 2],[4,2,5]]) - x * np.eye(3)` in your example? Maybe you could ask this on https://math.stackexchange.com/ if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You only give your matrix to the eigenvalue solver

```py
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[-2, -4, 2], [-2, 1, 2],[4,2,5]])
x, V = np.linalg.eig(A)
assert np.allclose(V @ np.diag(x), A @ V)
```

For your example it gives `x = array([-5.,  3.,  6.])`
Each element of `x` plugged in the expression `np.det(A - x * np.eye(len(A)))` will be close to zero.

for instance

```py
np.linalg.det(A - np.eye(len(A))*x[0])
```

gives `4.849454171562702e-13`

`V` is the eigenvector matrix.

Comment: Actually in my matrix the unknown  `x`  is also present in off diagonal elements. This is the reason  I cannot use the build in function to calculate eigen values and eigen vectors

Comment: So you solve the eigenvalues for the constant part of the matrix and for each eigenvalue you add `x`.

Comment: the solutions for det(A - (y+x) I) = 0 are the solutions for det((A - xI) - yI) = 0

Comment: For systems like 3x3 it may work; but my actual problem size is 100x100. computing the determinant is really difficult

Comment: I am not suggesting you to compute the determinat, I am only saying what is a consequence of the eigen equation.

Comment: I dont know, could you please explain. I am interested to solve  eigen values of the matrix A which is a function of  x.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240786/discussion-between-acoustic-python-and-bob).

Comment: If the function is arbitrary, for each value of X you compute the matrix numerically then solve one eigenvalue problem.